# Callback / dispatch event from Interceptor to Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signals

I have an app with AngularJS.

This app makes use of many directives with and without isolated scope. There are two services that loads and dispatch data using a sub/pub system. No big deal.

Now I have the follow scenario: everytime any service start a "get/post/etc" method, I want to show a preloader. When the data comes back, I want hide the preloader. Well, ok, the services dispatch an event, the Preloader directive listen for that and, on success/error callback, a new event is dispatched and I hide the preloader.

But in real world it is not useful. I need to dispatch events like "onStartLoad" from my services and it is polluting the code. Here is an example of one method inside my Services:

```
var service = {
    onOffersLoaded: new signals.Signal(),
    // (... many other events/signals here)

    // On start any request event:
    onStartAny: new signals.Signal(),

    // On end any request event:       
    onEndAny: new signals.Signal(),

    getOffers: function(store) {
        // Dispatch that the request is about to begin:
        service.onStartAny.dispatch();

        var url = config.apiUrl + "/my-ending-point-here";
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data) {
                // Dispatch that the request got back:
                service.onEndAny.dispatch();

                service.onOffersLoaded.dispatch(data, store);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                // Dispatch that the request got back:
                service.onEndAny.dispatch();

                service.onError.dispatch(error);
            });
    },
```

As you can see, I need to spread `service.onStartAny.dispatch();` and `service.onEndAny.dispatch();` all around my methods. It is very annoying and dirty.

Then I thought: I could use a **[Interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**. E very time data comes in or out of my application, an Interceptor could 'catch' those requests and it could dispatch an event to my Preloader directive. Doing this, my Services would not have to deal with those "starting/ending requests" events.

But I do not know how to "access" the directive from my Interceptor OR how to add callbacks to my interceptor from the Directive. Is it possible? Or the only way would be "rootScope broadcast" from Interceptor?

Any help is very appreciate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was simple: since Interceptors are just angular's factory, it is injected in my controller just like any other service.

So, in the end, this is my interceptor:

```
angular.module("offersApp").factory("preloaderInterceptor", function($q) {
"ngInject";

var interceptor = {

    onRequestStart: new signals.Signal(),
    onRequestEnd: new signals.Signal(),

    request: function(config) {
        interceptor.onRequestStart.dispatch();
        return config;
    },

    requestError: function(rejection) {
        interceptor.onRequestEnd.dispatch();
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    },

    response: function(response) {
        interceptor.onRequestEnd.dispatch();
        return response;
    },

    responseError: function(rejection) {
        interceptor.onRequestEnd.dispatch();
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

};

return interceptor;
});
```

And this is my preloader directive:

```
angular.module("offersApp").directive("preloader", function ($timeout, preloaderInterceptor) {
    "ngInject";
    return {
        template: '<div id="preloader"><div class="loading"></div></div>',
        replace: true,
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {},

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            var showPreloader = function() {
                element.css({display: 'block', opacity: 1});
            }

            var hidePreloader = function() {
                element.css({opacity: 0});
                var promise = $timeout(function() {
                    element.css({display: 'none'});
                }, 600);
            }

            preloaderInterceptor.onRequestStart.add(showPreloader);
            preloaderInterceptor.onRequestEnd.add(hidePreloader);
        }
    };
});
```